# How can I send a custom dimension after page load separately to first page view?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

So I have a GA setup through Google Tag Manager. On one page I have some JS (counts the numbers of a particular class) which returns a value which I'd like to pass through into a custom dimension. Only problem is that the original pageview runs at page load and this JS needs to run as Page Ready.

I've tried two methods and both seems to have issues.

1. At the end of my JS I put the below. This didn't send it as I believe GTM creates names for each instance of GA e.g. ga.13 instead of just ga. This did send however if the visitor then went to another page and didn't abandon as I believe it's sent on the next pageview.

```
ga('set', 'dimension62', dimensionValue);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

2. I used GTMs own GA Pageview to trigger on page load however this seems to have duplicated a pageview for that page.

Any ideas on how I can send this through to GA?

Answer (score 0):

Send it at page load with a non-interaction event.